# Using uIPv6 without Contiki

Tags: contiki

I'm looking to use uIPv6 on a microcontroller with no OS, using 6LoWPAN & an 802.15.4 radio.  Contiki is supposed to be modular, but I'm finding a lot of Contiki dependencies in the uIP source code.  Could anyone provide any insight in separating the current version of uIP from Contiki?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compile Contiki modules for different target motes (E.g. Sky, Z1). Contiki makefiles solves the dependencies and links them and creates an executable that is specific for your target. 
There are many useful code samples in Contiki samples folder. Also following the Hello world example [link](http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/Hello_World) may help.

Answer (score 0):

It exist a solution for your question, Telecom Bretagne ported the Contiki µIPv6 Stack for Arduino platforms. 
[Link to Wiki](http://%3Chttps://github.com/telecombretagne/Arduino-IPv6Stack/wiki)
[Link to github repo](https://github.com/telecombretagne/Arduino-IPv6Stack)

Good luck.